# How can I create a Google compliant video sitemap

Tags: 6, files

I'm use Drupal 6, and I'd like to be able to create a sitemap that conforms to the [Google Video Sitemap protocol](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=80472).  Are there any modules for this?

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more specific.  Do you want a sitemap of uploaded videos?  Nodes with videos on?  A sitemap that is _actually_ a video that walks you through the site?

Comment: i create content type Videos and add field video. now i want create video site map for add google EX: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=80472

Comment: I've just posted [an article](http://onlinebusinessbuilders.co.uk/video-tutorials/how-create-google-video-sitemap-drupal) on this. I'm using emfield and media:youtube modules to embed my YouTube Videos but the method should work for many other applications. It essentially uses the mighty Views to generate the Video sitemap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://drupal.org/node/451234#comment-5194170) should be of some help.  In fact, definitely follow that thread for updates on integrating with XML site map.

You might also want to check out the [Schema.org](http://drupal.org/project/schemaorg) module - that might be helpful.  Either way, it looks like you'll have to add fields manually that contain video length etc.